# How to set a custom TMPDIR for Chrome Driver when running on Linux?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I used to be able to launch Chrome Driver using a custom tmp directory by running the following:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                    .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("TMPDIR", WORK_DIR.getCanonicalPath()))
                    .build(), options);
```

But I upgraded to chromium 75 and chromedriver 75 and now I cannot seem to do this anymore.

I experience this error when I try to set the TMPDIR:

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

How can I prevent chromedriver from using the /tmp default directory when running?

Comment: Create logs and check what error do you see?

Comment: This *is* the message from the logs that I see. Nothing else useful there.

Comment: Maybe report it to the chrome/ chromium e-mail group if there is one? can u use an older one for a few releases till they fix? https://www.chromium.org/developers/discussion-groups

Comment: yes that is what i'm currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following options and confirm if it works or not.

```
options.addArguments("–no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("–disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```

Comment: hi this does not work. thanks for contributing though.